# Getting tag of Multiple Checkbox from Custom Adapter binded on AlerDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, baseadapter, android-checkbox

I have an `AlerDialog` which displays a *list of items* with `checkboxes`.I am trying to get the `tag (Checkbox.getTag())` of selected `checkboxes` and append them to a `String`. Then i want to get this `String` from the class where i have declared the `AlerDialog`.

**Is there a way to do that, or i should change the logic of implemetation?**

Here is my `CustomAdapter`:

```
    public class DepartmentsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<DepartmentModel> departmentsList;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public DepartmentsAdapter(Context mContext, List<DepartmentModel> departmentsList){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.departmentsList = departmentsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return departmentsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return departmentsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.departments_list_item, null);

        DepartmentModel deptModel = (DepartmentModel) getItem(position);

        CheckBox deptChBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deptCheckBox);
        TextView deptName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deptNameTextView);

        deptChBox.setTag(deptModel.departmentCode);
        deptName.setText(deptModel.departmentName);

        /*deptChBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                buttonView.getTag();
            }
        });*/

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here is the snippet where i am setting that list to `AlertDialog` and where i am trying to get selected `checkboxes` from:

```
 final DepartmentsAdapter departmentsAdapter = new DepartmentsAdapter(mActivity, deptList);

    mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
        mDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.departments));
        mDialog.setAdapter(departmentsAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Get from selection what you want
                Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Clicked CheckBOx: " + which);
                final String departmentCode = deptList.get(which).departmentCode;
            }
        });

    mDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thnx dudes for helping, however i managed to solve it. Here is my solution:

```
    public class DepartmentsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

    private Context mContext;
    private List<DepartmentModel> departmentsList;
    private HashMap<String, Boolean> hashMap;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    //Constructor
    public DepartmentsAdapter(Context mContext, List<DepartmentModel> departmentsList, List<String> checkedItems){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.departmentsList = departmentsList;
        hashMap = new HashMap<>();

        if(checkedItems != null) {
            for (String item : checkedItems) {
                hashMap.put(item, true);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return departmentsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return departmentsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.departments_list_item, null);

        DepartmentModel deptModel = (DepartmentModel) getItem(position);

        CheckBox deptChBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deptCheckBox);
        TextView deptName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deptNameTextView);

        deptChBox.setTag(deptModel.departmentCode);
        deptName.setText(deptModel.departmentName);

        if(hashMap.get(deptModel.departmentCode) != null && hashMap.get(deptModel.departmentCode)){
            deptChBox.setChecked(true);
        }

        deptChBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        String deptCode = (String) buttonView.getTag();
        hashMap.put(deptCode, isChecked);
    }

    public List<String> getCheckedItems() {
        ArrayList<String> checkedItems = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String deptCode : hashMap.keySet()){
            if(hashMap.get(deptCode)){
                checkedItems.add(deptCode);
            }
        }
        return checkedItems;
    }
}
```

and on `AlerDialog` i call it as:

```
 final List<String> checkedItems = departmentsAdapter.getCheckedItems();
 deptCodeString = Arrays.toString(checkedItems.toArray()).replace(", ", ",").replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your adapter class

```
 private CheckBox mSelectedRB;
 private int selected = -1;
 private String title = "";
```

And then in your getView method

```
    title = this.items.get(position);
   // deptName.setText(title);
    deptChBox.setTag(title);
        deptChBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if(position != selected && mSelectedRB != null){
                mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
            }

            selected = position;
            mSelectedRB = (CheckBox)view;
            selectedUrl = (String)view.getTag();
            //notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    });

  if(selected != position){
        deptChBox.setChecked(false);
    }else{
        deptChBox.setChecked(true);
        if(deptChBox != null && deptChBox != mSelectedRB){
            mSelectedRB = deptChBox;
        }
    }
```

Now you can call it in your dialog class with no problem.
Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://www.ulduzsoft.com/2012/07/android-dialog-to-choose-a-directory-or-file-based-on-alertdialog/ might be useful...